Абсолютное позиционирование элементов
Дочерние блоки можно позиционировать относительно родителя 1/2/3 уровня и тд. То того родителя которому присвоено свойство
position: relative;

То есть в данный момент позиционирую на 2 родителя выше. Но если присвоить 1 родителю свойство
container-type: size;

Дочерние элементы будут позиционироваться относительно 1 родителя, вместо второго...
Вопрос в том, как сделать чтобы и текст масштабировался на дочерних блоках относительно первого родителя. И дочерние блоки позиционировать относительно 2 родителя...
Не внося поправки в html документ, только за счет css..?
Не понимаю, почему не работает если делать так
height: 200px;
container-type: size;
font-size: 2cqb;

Размер шрифта будет статичным, работает если родителю присвоить
container-type: size;



.ps {
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   background: red;
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.p {
  display:flex;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  margin-top:auto;
  container-type: size;
  
}
.p .text {font-size: 32cqb}

.pos {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    background: blue;
}
<div class='ps'>

  <div class='p'>
    <div class='pos'></div>
    <div class='text'>asdsd</div>
  </div>
</div>



Как не внося изменения в html, заставить позиционировать синий квадрат, относительно красного??

Вопрос про позиционирование без примера HTML довольно сложно понять

Добавил пример, как позиционировать синий квадрат относительно красного? Не внося изменения в html, только css с сохранение маштабировать текст относительно зеленого

Никак.
Меняйте вёрстку или отказывайтесь от contaner-type. Блок с container-type: size становится containing block относительно которого позиционируется absolute.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block
